# GeoDjango raster field display on Leaflet

Tags: python, openlayers-2, leaflet, geodjango, django

In the new Django version support raster field and I follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/) manual for GeoDjango raster field and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285780/geodjango-tif-import-with-raster-needs-to-be-opened-in-write-mode-to-change-val) for add raster I have built a simple demo.

Here the code :

settings.py

postgis database backend

```
'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Elevation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rast = models.RasterField()
```

All works fine without error. But I have one BIG question where I don't know how to complete it.

How do I display this raster in some web map like Leaflet?

Comment: geoserver can do this

Answer (score 1):

You will need something to tile the raster and then serve these as tiles to Leaflet as if it was a background map. You probably want to use GeoServer or something similar to do this.